# Can not locate rest api with Spring-boot camel restlet

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, restlet

Hi I am using springboot with Camel, my routes are getting started 
correctly but can not trigger rest apis as i can not locate them.

***pom.xml***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.camel</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-camel</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>spring-camel</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <camel.version>2.21.0</camel.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-restlet</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

***application.properties***

```
camel.springboot.xmlRoutes = true 
camel.springboot.xmlRoutes = classpath:xml-route/*.xml 
camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true 
camel.springboot.xmlRests = true 
camel.springboot.xmlRests = classpath:xml-rest/*.xml 
server.port = 8084 
spring.application.name = spring-camel
```

***Springboot Main class:***

```
@SpringBootApplication 
@EnableAutoConfiguration 
public class SpringCamelApplication { 

public static void main(String[] args) { 
   SpringApplication.run(SpringCamelApplication.class, args); 
 } 
}
```

***REST ROUTE:***

```
<rests xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
 <rest id="rest-route">
  <get uri="/test">
    <to uri="direct:test"/>
  </get>
 </rest>
</rests>
```

***LOG after application started:***

```
2018-05-28 12:34:46.178  INFO 4852 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2018-05-28 12:34:46.211  INFO 4852 --- [           main] o.a.camel.component.file.FileEndpoint    : Endpoint is configured with noop=true so forcing endpoint to be idempotent as well
2018-05-28 12:34:46.211  INFO 4852 --- [           main] o.a.camel.component.file.FileEndpoint    : Using default memory based idempotent repository with cache max size: 1000
2018-05-28 12:34:46.357  INFO 4852 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector    : Starting CamelMainRunController to ensure the main thread keeps running
2018-05-28 12:34:46.361  INFO 4852 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: first-route started and consuming from: direct://test
2018-05-28 12:34:46.374  INFO 4852 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: second-route started and consuming from: file://E://inputFolder?noop=true
2018-05-28 12:34:46.384  INFO 4852 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: route1 started and consuming from: restlet:///test?restletMethods=GET
2018-05-28 12:34:46.385  INFO 4852 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Total 3 routes, of which 3 are started
2018-05-28 12:34:46.388  INFO 4852 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.21.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.471 seconds
2018-05-28 12:34:46.395  INFO 4852 --- [           main] c.c.springcamel.SpringCamelApplication   : Started SpringCamelApplication in 3.543 seconds (JVM running for 3.878)
```

So clearly it says ' route1 started and consuming from: 
restlet:///test?restletMethods=GET' but when i call 
http://localhost:8084/test its says unreachable.

Badly need help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have `application.xml` and not `application.properties`? Further, the first `xmlRoutes` or `xmlRests` are redundant as you later on define a classpath. The [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html) states that you can either disable such features or define the location. It would also be helpful if you post your route definition as it is unclear where you set the `server.port` actually. Probably it used the default port (80 or 8080) instead. Btw, `http:localhost:8084/test` isn't a valid URI anyways, maybe you meant `http://localhost:8084/test`?

Comment: That was all typing mistake, now edited them all. Thanks for your reply, Now i have also added the rest route

Comment: I have checked with `http://localhost:8080/test` but still same, unreachable.

Comment: I'm still not sure where or how your `server.port` property is used to define the restlet port actaully. Some Spring-Boot magic that I'm not aware of? I usually don't use XML configuration so my experience is rather limited with that. The [official documentation](http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html) states that you can configure it within the REST DSL like this: `<restConfiguration bindingMode="auto" component="restlet" port="8084"/>`

Comment: Hi, i have commented that port in `applicaiton.properties` file and added restconfiguration inside the rest route `<rests xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<restConfiguration bindingMode="auto" component="restlet" port="8084" host="localhost"/>
<rest id="rest-route">
 <get uri="/test">
  <to uri="direct:test"/>
 </get>
</rest>
</rests>` but it still not working, have i done correctly ?

Comment: Big thanks to Roman Vottner, i got the idea from your suggestion,  got it worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it worked adding the rest configuration in spring context. Just added below code

```
    @Bean
    public RestConfiguration getRest()
    {
        RestConfiguration restconfig=new RestConfiguration();
        restconfig.setPort(8081);
        restconfig.setComponent("restlet");
        //restconfig.setHost("localhost");
        restconfig.setContextPath("/api");
        restconfig.setBindingMode("auto");
        return restconfig;
    }
```